# What is an int[][]

Tags: java, arrays, int

So far I have been working in codding all I faced was `int[]` Which basically is an array, say I have

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
System.out.println("Number="+numbers[2]);
```

Output result: 3

I recently came across needs of Levenshtein distance algorithm, which uses `int[][]` as `int[][] distance = new int[lhs.length() + 1][rhs.length() + 1];`

I would really appreciate is someone tell me when is a `int[][]` used and why?

Comment: Valekum assalam - Google  "Multi Dimensional array"

Comment: It's an array of arrays but can be called a multi-dimensional array or a matrix. Take the 3rd index of the outer array, you'll get an inner array, which will contain a set of `int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would really appreciate is someone tell me when is a int[][] used
>   and why?

we use `int[][]`, when we want to work with matrix an array with two dimension :

`int[] array`; //represent an array with one dimension for example `{1, 2, 3}`

now, what if you want to make a matrix like this :

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

How you can represent this with arrays?

the answer is `int[][]` array with 2 demotion.

Then you can initialize your array with size, for example in the example of documentation, that i already mention :

```
int[][] array = new int[5][4];// Multidimensional array: 5x4
```

`array` is an array of `int` of 2 dimension with `5x4` size, so this can represented like this :

```
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a multi-dimensional array, each entry represents another array.

Answer (score 0):

int[][] is a array of integer array. It is a matrix of int.

You can check these links that explain well the structure array of array. 
https://www.leepoint.net/data/arrays/arrays-2D-2.html

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077367/learn-java/array-of-arrays.html